# I need to destroy the instance of a class within itself

Tags: c#, destroy

Before I come to the core question, I provide you with some background.
I am working on some common functions for GTA V mods. The focus here is a Checkpoint class. This class gets instantiated as usual. All necessary parameters for a checkpoint are injected in the constructor, which then creates the checkpoint in game. A private int handle keeps the connection between this class and the real checkpoint. This is also necessary because of some properties which can be changed during lifetime.
Later the user can call the DeleteCheckpoint method and here is the problem:
The instance of the Checkpoint class is now decoupled from the "real" checkpoint in game as it doesn't exist anymore and is no longer valid because of this.
So I would like to destroy this instance (set to null) right after the native call to delete the in-game checkpoint.
Any idea?

Comment: Since C# is a garbage collected language, just `null` the reference in the code calling the `DeleteCheckpoint` method and let the CLR destroy the object for you.

Comment: .NET does not have a way to delete an object. I'm unclear on what you want to do.

Comment: but this = null;
is not possible.

Comment: I'd advice implementing the Disposable pattern which will do something *similar*. Objects don't keep track of all possible references to themselves, so you can't null out (all of) the references to the object.

Comment: Did you tried   this.Despose();

Comment: Thanks, Damien_The_Unbeliever explained it. So all I can do is to advice the user to destroy the instance himself in his code by mentioning it in the XML comment.

Comment: In .NET (and other garbage-collected environments) deleting an object is simply a matter of letting go of any references to it.

Comment: I have just implemented a simple solution: after calling the native which destroys the checkpoint, I set the integer handle to 0 and now, within all methods and properties I check this handle for 0 and if it's true I throw an ArgumentNullException.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - that's not the point.

Comment: It sounds like `InvalidOperationException` would be more appropriate, or perhaps `ObjectDisposedException` if you'd handled the disconnection via the disposable mechanism. Throwing `ArgumentNullException` when the calling code hasn't called a method with a null argument where null arguments aren't allowed is a bug.

Comment: Great advice @JonHanna. :)
I'm going to change that.
I don't use the Dispose pattern here but I bet the game does. So ObjectDisposedException sounds like the right choice for me. I have forgotten this exception even exists. I am a case where a list of all exceptions would be a great thing to have because I tend to forget things I haven't used for a long time (or never).

Comment: Match what you actually do yourself in the object in question; if the object you are calling the method on uses `Dispose()` to put it into a no-longer-in-use state **and** that is why it is in that state, throw `ObjectDisposedException` because that explains what the caller did wrong. Otherwise you need to more general "you're trying to use something for some purpose it can't (currently anyway) serve" which is what `InvalidOperationException` describes.